# How can I detect Android dark mode in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing an Android game with Unity. Currently, I have an option for players to choose between dark/light UI schemes. Also, I'm aware that recent Android versions feature dark mode, which makes the system and some external apps' UI look dark or light.

How is it possible to check if the user has enabled dark mode in Android's settings, so the game's UI theme will be synced with OS's theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity doesn't have any native method to check the Theme Mode, you have to use some [plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html) for that.

You can build your own, use an open-source package ([like this one](https://github.com/FramePush/darkmodedetect)) or search on the store for it.

*I know that your question is explicitly for Android, but keep in mind that you will need different ways of check the Mode depending on the platform*.